# What does it mean, when SSL_get_fd returns -1?

Tags: ssl, openssl, frida

I am analysing a programm with frida that definitely connects to some server via SSL. When I call `SSL_get_fd`, it returns -1. From the documentation I see that this means that `ssl` doesnt wrap a socket (BIO is definitely configured, as I can access it via `SSL_get_rbio`). How can openssl connect to a server without a socket? Is there any way to see the peer address/port without accessing the underlying socket?

Comment: What openssl version so you use? Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Can you tell us what did you do ?

Comment: What OS do you use? Anyway, search for "netstat", maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @RemigijusPankevičius Android, `netstat` show the remote it that the process communicate with  , but if the process talk with some ip , with debugging we can see each SSL data send to each IP