# SSL_get_fd return -1

Tags: ssl, openssl, file-descriptor, android-debug, frida

I have tried to debug android application to print out [SSL_write](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_write.html) and [SSL_read](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_read.html) data with that [project](https://github.com/fanxs-t/Android-SSL_read-write-Hook/blob/master/frida-hook.py)  and print out the file descriptor (to get src&dst ip ) with [SSL_get_fd](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_get_fd)

But for some `SSL*` the function `SSL_get_fd` always return -1 instead of return correct fd , and for another `SSL*` the function `SSL_get_fd` return the correct fd .

When I tried to use function `SSL_is_init_finished` just for check on those `SSL*` that return fd = -1 , I got 1(true)

I saw a same question on : [What does it mean, when SSL_get_fd returns -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278484/what-does-it-mean-when-ssl-get-fd-returns-1)  but there is no answer there.

How can I get the correct fd from `SSL *` ?